# how to properly read a serializable from a parcelable?

Tags: java, serialization, parcelable

I have a serializable object (ArrayList) within a Parcelable object.  I am trying to read the serializable object, and I can't figure out how exactly to reconstruct it after reading:

```
public class WifiAP implements Parcelable {

public String _mac;
public String _mac2;
public String _ssid;
public boolean _dualband;
public int _band;  // kilohertz
public int _band2;
ArrayList<Integer> _rssis;

public Packet _beacon;

public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
    out.writeString(_mac);
    out.writeString(_mac2);
    out.writeString(_ssid);

    if(_dualband)
        out.writeInt(1);
    else
        out.writeInt(0);

    out.writeInt(_band);
    out.writeInt(_band2);
    out.writeSerializable(_rssis);
}

private WifiAP(Parcel in) {
    _mac = in.readString();
    _mac2 = in.readString();
    _ssid = in.readString();

    if(in.readInt()==1)
        _dualband=true;
    else
        _dualband=false;

    _band = in.readInt();
    _band2 = in.readInt();
    _rssis = in.readSerializable(); // help here, this throws an error
}
```

How do you properly recreate the ArrayList from Parcel.readSerializable?

Comment: What error do you get? Have you tried casting the returned serializable to (ArrayList<Integer>) ?

Comment: my error is: Type mismatch: cannot convert from Serializable to ArrayList<Integer>.  So maybe casting is the right thing to do

Comment: you should restate this as an answer rather than a comment, so I can up vote and select it as an answer ;) then you get karma

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
   _rssis = (ArrayList<Integer>)  in.readSerializable();
```

Comment: `readSerializable` is deprecated from `Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU`. Instead of this you can use `ArrayList<Integer> list = in.readSerializable(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader(), ArrayList.class);`